# Algorithms: Transformation without rotation

Tags: algorithm, transformation

Is there a name for 2D transformation having the following parameters:

- shift_x,
- shift_y,
- scale.

Transformation does not use any rotation... Thanks for your help.

Comment: This might be a good question to migrate to the math SE site. This is fundamentally a question about geometry.

Comment: Also, are you looking for a name that encompasses these kinds of transformations, or one for a single transformation that involves all of these transformations, in (what I assume to be) the prescribed order?

Comment: I disagree that it should go to math.SE.  This is a question that spans too many SE sites - math, EE, statistics, SO, game dev, photography and topics already on SO, such as computer vision.  At it's core, it's math + an algorithm, but actual usage or interpretation could be very open.

Comment: Without scaling it would be displacement. With isotropic scaling and rotation is called similarity. I don't think it has a unique name though.

Answer (score 2):

Shift_x and Shift_y count as a *translation*. I don't know that there is a specific term for a transformation that involves both a translation and scaling at the same time... particularly since the order in which these transformations are carried out can affect the result (depending on how the scaling is done, this might not be true).

Comment: Do scales count as projection matrices?  Projections are idempotent while scales can be applied multiple times to produce different matrices.

Comment: scale is sometimes named "dilatation" : Projection is the method to transform n dimention matrix to a n-k dimension matrix... example: if you have a real 3D object ... to represent it on a flat 2D screen you need a projection method.

Comment: Weird. I thought it was normal terminology to call just multiplying the coordinates by a factor a "projection from the origin". Editing my answer to account for this misunderstanding...

Comment: This is kind of weirding me out. I know that "projection" can refer to the changing dimensions thing you guys are talking about... as in "projecting a line on to a plane"... but I thought I remembered learning at some point during my childhood that "projection" could be used in another, perhaps in a more basic analytic-geometric sense, to talk about multiplying coordinates by a factor. Sorry for the confusion... but thanks for setting the record straight.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the other answers are correct.  I am going to add a terminological difference.

Scaling, shift, and rotation are the three transformations that are the most frequent cases of affine transformation of data.  Reflection, shearing, and others are seen, but not as commonly mentioned.

These three may go by several names independently or in conjunction:

- Scaling: Scaling, re-scaling, normalization, dilation
- Shift: Shift, centering, re-centering
- Scaling + shift: Normalization
- Rotation: Rotation, projection
- Scaling + shift + rotation: steps seen in PCA, SVD, or called "whitening" or "sphering" in some contexts.

Unfortunately, these may be interpreted more or less loosely in different contexts.  For instance, I generally interpret normalization to address centering and scaling (usually leading to "z-scores"), others may assume it is just scaling.  I prefer to never use "sphering" or "whitening" as terms, because these are imprecise and not used in more than a few disciplines.

In statistics, shift or translation may occur when one "centers" data to have a mean of 0.  Scaling occurs when one desires, say, unit variance (or a standard deviation of 1), for the sample.  Rotation often occurs in order to project onto orthogonal dimensions.  Because of the scaling and centering, this often utilizes orthonormal projections.

Update 1: The OP asked only about 2 dimensions, but one should note that these transformations are all allowed to be in many dimensions.  There are no restrictions to 1, 2, or any number of other dimensions, nor any special terms for small #s of dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for one particular [Affine transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) :

in french (sorry I cannot find the name in english) "[une affinité](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinit%C3%A9_%28math%C3%A9matiques%29)" (it should be affinity in english) is the affine transformation made of **one translation + one homotethy** ?

"les affinités" include :

- Id
- homotethy
- scaling
- symetry
- projections

(no rotations)

---

EDIT

All this transformations are made of one homotethy in one direction and the identity in the complementary.

let f be an "affinité"

Let E be a vectorial space, and F and G such that : [image]

if [image]  then [image]

Comment: Affine transformations count rotations, which I interpret OP does not want to include.

Comment: @Michael, I'm talking about one particular affine transformation called affinité, not all affine transformation.

Comment: I somehow missed the "one particular" in your post, but thanks for the clarification.

Comment: In my opinion, the affine transformation uses 2 different scales and 1 or 2 rotation(s)...

Comment: @Johnas, all the affine transformations included in "affinité" are the sum of one homotethy on one subspace and the Identity on the complementary.